# iPad programming, any way to invert color programmatically?

Tags: ios, ipad, colors

You know how the iPad can invert colors? For the app I'm working on we wanted to have a button that would invert the colors for one of the views the same way.  Does the sdk have any kind of support for something like that already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is an easy way at the moment. CALayer has a compositingFilter property which is described as

> A CoreImage filter used to composite
>   the receiver’s contents with the
>   background. Animatable.

It's available since iOS 2.0 but it also says:

> While the CALayer class exposes this
>   property, Core Image is **not available
>   in iOS**. Currently the filters
>   available for this property are
>   undefined.

Core Image would have been ideal for that purpose, it does provide a [filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) (CIColorInvert) to invert colors.

Another apporach would be: Change the color properties of the UI controls you are using, though I doubt that everything will look they way you expect, as there may be gradients and such. You have to implement your own small algorithm to invert a given color.

I see only the hard way: You have to draw your controls manually with drawRect and invert the colors with your own algorithm there.